# Building the solution failing after switching to x64

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, c++-cli

The solution is set up as follows:

1. vb.net test application, x64, references 3
2. C# library, x64
3. C++/CLI library, x64, references 2

The build config used to be win32 for c++/cli and "any cpu" for the other two. Then I switched to x64 but couldn't get it to compile by just switching around c++cli but also had to switch the other two to x64 (don't remember the error exactly, something about version mismatch).

Ok, then it was compiling semi-fine for a while. Every now and then I'd get the error

"Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run."

I couldn't figure out so I just hit f5 again if that happened.

Now though I'm getting the same error over and over when I try to build the test application (the other 2 compile fine individually). Does anybody know why?

EDIT: oh also, the release build works, its only the debug one thats failing.

EDIT2: for no apparent reason, it decided to work again. Still would like to figure this out though since I'm sure this won't be the last time I see this error.

Comment: Your anti-malware product is interfering, find something better.